# Excel - How to highlight entire row if a specific cell is different from the cell above?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, conditional-formatting

I am trying to apply conditional formatting in excel in which each first occurrence in a column has a highlight on the entire row. The desired result is as follows:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 |  |
| 2 |  |
| **8** | **Highlight this entire row** |
| **5** | **Highlight this entire row** |
| 5 |  |
| **7** | **Highlight this entire row** |

I currently have the formula "A3<>A2", but that highlight the last occurrence instead of the first. I don't know how to apply the highlight to all cells on the same row.

UPDATE: Apparently excel behaves differently for text and numeric values. My data looks like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Apple |  |
| Apple |  |
| **Banana** | **Highlight this entire row** |
| **Kiwi** | **Highlight this entire row** |
| Kiwi |  |
| **Apple** | **Highlight this entire row** |

Comment: try "A2<>A1" when starting in A2 with your format condition

Comment: Still highlights last occurence

Comment: Please post a screenshot where we can see the data (with column headers and rows) plus the open format condition dialogue

Comment: I believe your first row should be highlighted too, don't you think?

Comment: First row may be highlighted too. The first row is not very interesting

Comment: OK, so this works for numeric values, but highlights the last occurrence for text

Comment: is your data always grouped like that?  If not, you'll need to rethink that approach.

Comment: My data is sorted by 'fruit type', so the last entry "Apple" is not possible.

Comment: It works both for numbers and text, i think the problem is range that you apply to formatting. If you use a2<>a1 you must apply to range from second but not first row. Check my answer

Answer (score 3):

### Conditional Formatting - Entire Row For First Occurrence in Column

- The issue you are facing is that you have selected e.g. the range `2:10` (focus on **2**) and e.g. you are applying the corrected (`$`) formula `=$A3<>$A2` which does what is expected: it highlights the last occurrence in a group i.e. if the value of the **next** row (**3**) is different than the value of the current row (**2**) then highlight row **2**.
- To highlight the first occurrence in a group, you need `=$A2<>$A1` as correctly posted by **user11222393** since the first row you selected is row **2** i.e. if the value of the **previous** row (**1**) is different than the value of the current row (**2**) then highlight row **2**.
- My solution will work similarly if the data is sorted. It will not highlight the first row of repeating groups though, as illustrated in the screenshot below.
- You will notice the difference between the solutions best by sorting the data in another column. Mine should have fewer highlighted rows.

**Usage**

- Select the entire rows of the range and goto `Home -> Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Use formula...` (you know the drill) and e.g. use

  ```
  =COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)=1
  ```

  for the first row being row 2.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=$A2<>$A1
```

Take a look at `$` symbols. If you don't use it it will highlight only 1 cell, because it will compare `A2` to `A1`, `B2` to `B1` and so on.

Result:

[image]